# How do I create multiple entries in Jabref from bibtex data?

Tags: bibtex

Suppose I have bibtex data for, say, 10 articles. Is there a way to, within jabref, create 10 entries from this?

A solution is to just open the .bib file and paste the data in.

Comment: This post is belong to stack overflow

Comment: Please specify in what format you have the data. If it's already in BibTeX, simply open the .bib, or copy its contents into another .bib

Answer (score 4):

Select the text that forms the BibTex source of the multiple data entries and drag this into the library view of JabRef. You could probably drag all the files in, however I have not tested this. 
[alt text http://inverse.seednet.eu/snaps/jvvuow.png](http://inverse.seednet.eu/snaps/jvvuow.png)

Comment: That was an incredibly simple (and unexpected) solution! +1

Answer (score 2):

go to File, Append Database. then browse in to bibtex files folder, you can select multiple files in a row, then click ok, if you have 20 bibtex or txt files, they will be all loaded to one bib file. It was great, solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I often get BibTeX source code from [citeulike.org](http://www.citeulike.org/), and I copy/paste this BibTeX source directly into JabRef by:

1. Menu: *BibTex* -> *New Entry* (Ctrl^N, or the green + button)
2. select a random type; I typically just pick Article
3. Down the bottom, in the new edit view, select the BibTeX source tab
4. Replace the BibTeX source in that tab, with that of one paper

And repeat this for all papers.

(OT: also, make sure to check the *Web search* menu.)

Comment: Ah, that's actually what I do. I'm asking for a way to take the bibtex data for, say 20 files, and create 20 entries all at once (e.g. on MathSciNet I can get the bibtex data for all papers by a given author at once). Of course, one solution is to just paste this into the .bib file itself.